# XML return into separate node elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to return results in a specific format

```
<Applicants xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Applicant>
        <Name>John Smith</Name>
        <Address>1 Smiths Close</Address>
    </Applicant>
    <Applicant>
        <Name>Peter Smith</Name>
        <Address>2 Smiths Close</Address>
    </Applicant>
</Applicants>
```

but with my current query

```
select A.Name
    , ANL.name
    , A.address AS Address
    , ANL.address AS Address
    from Agents A 
        left join AgentsNonLatin ANL 
            On A.Pn = ANL.Pn AND A.Kd = ANL.kd 
    FOR XML RAW('Applicant'), ROOT('Applicants'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

I get them combined into a single `<Applicant>` node.

```
<Applicants xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Applicant>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Name>Peter Smith</Name>
    <Address>1 Smiths Close</Address>
    <Address>2 Smiths Close</Address>
  </Applicant>
</Applicants>
```

Any ideas about what needs to change to return them in the required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Union here

```
SELECT 
      A.Name
    , A.Address 
    FROM Agents A 
UNION
SELECT 
      ANL.Name
    , ANL.Address AS Address
    FROM AgentsNonLatin ANL 
FOR XML RAW('Applicant'), ROOT('Applicants'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```